# Given $(1+x^2)^2(1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n+4}a_r\cdot x^r$. If $a_0,a_1,a_2$ are in A.P, then value of $n$ can be:

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $(1+x^2)^2(1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n+4}a_r\cdot x^r$. If $a_0,a_1,a_2$ are in A.P, then value of $n$ can be:

$(A)$ $n=2$ or $3$,
$(B)$ $n=2$ only,
$(C)$ $n=3$ only,
$(D)$ $n=4$

My attempt is as follows:

Put $x=0$,

$$1=a_0\tag{1}$$

Put $x=-1$

$$0=a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+\cdots\cdots\tag{2}$$

No of terms are $n+5$,

**Case $1$:** $n$ is even $\implies$ no of terms will be odd

Hence equation $(2)$ can be written as follows:-

$$0=a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+\cdots\cdots+a_{n+4}$$
$$0=-\dfrac{n+4}{2}\cdot d+a_{n+4}$$
$$0=a_0+\left(n+4-1-\dfrac{n+4}{2}\right)\cdot d$$
$$a_0+(\dfrac{n+2}{2})\cdot d=0$$
$$1+\left(\dfrac{n+2}{2}\right)d=0$$
$$\dfrac{n+2}{2}\cdot d=-1$$

Let's put $n=2$
$$d=-\dfrac{1}{2}$$

**Case $2$:** $n$ is odd $\implies$ no of terms are even

$$0=-\dfrac{n+5}{2}\cdot d$$

In this case $d$ will be zero

From this calculation I am not able to decide what should be the answer, please help me in this.

FYI: Actual answer is option $A)$

Comment: You're acting as if *all* the coefficients are in arithmetic progression, but the problem only says the first three coefficients are in arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity should work for $|x^2|<1$ as well

$$(1+x)^n=(1+x^2)^{-2}\sum_{r=0}^{n+4}a_r x^r$$

Using [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

$$1+nx+\binom n2x^2+\cdots+x^n=a_0+a_1x+x^2(a_2-2a_0)+x^3a_3+\cdots$$

$$a_0=1,a_1=n,\binom n2=a_2-2$$

We need 
$$a_0+a_2=2a_1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+x^2)^2(1+x)^n=(1+2x^2+\cdots)(1+nx+{n\choose2}x^2+\cdots)=1+nx+\left({n\choose2}+2\right)x^2+\cdots$$ so we want $n$ such that $1,n,{n\choose2}+2$ are in AP. Can you take it from there?